# create playlist spotify API

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, spotify

I am trying to create a playlist using the Spotify API and am receiving the following error:

```js
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "Error parsing JSON."
  }
}
```

I am following the [example on this page](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/) that says to use the following curl request

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/thelinmichael/playlists" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"name\":\"A New Playlist\", \"public\":false}"
```

My code looks like this

```js
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{id}/playlists',
   method: "POST",
   data: {
     name: "test"
   },
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   success: function(response) {
     console.log(response);
   }
 });
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check your token again the ajax is correct

Comment: @HudsonPH i don't believe there is an issue with the token, as I am able to make other requests, it is just the POST request that is catching me

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I was not posting valid son. By using `JSON.stringify` I was able to solve this issue.

```
JSON.stringify({name: "test", public: false})
```

Complete code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{id}/playlists',
   method: "POST",
   data: {
     name: JSON.stringify({name: "test", public: false})
   },
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   success: function(response) {
     console.log(response);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Weird, it was almost as if the error message wasn't lying to you ;)

Comment: @zerohero hahaha, i know, still took me nearly a day to figure it out :-)

Comment: been there done that :P at least for next time you know